# My MySQLi dosen't update only inserts? What's wrong with my script?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
    $check_verified_user = mysqli_query("SELECT * from user_verified where user_mail = '$payer_email'");
    $user_verified = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conDB, "SELECT * FROM user_verified where user_mail = '$payer_email'"));

    if(mysqli_num_rows($check_verified_user) > 0) {
        mysqli_query($conDB, "UPDATE user_verified SET total_paid = total_paid + '$payment_amount' where user_mail = '$payer_email'");
    } else {
        mysqli_query($conDB, "INSERT into user_verified (user_mail,total_paid) VALUES ('$payer_email', '$payment_amount')");
    }
```

I don't know what's wrong with my script, it checks if the row exists, then if it exists it should update, but instead it inserts another row, which i don't understand...

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_verified WHERE user_mail = $payer_email";
$check_verified_user = mysqli_query($conDB, $query);
```

You basically wasn't giving it the database connection, so it was always coming back as not being greater than 0 rows. Personally, I always put my query into its own variable first, and this will ensure that you don't forget params for the `mysqli_query()` function. It also makes it easier to read, and allows you to use the query in other places if needed.

Comment: Thanks, i noticed i forgot the $conDB part haha :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do this method:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from user_verified where user_mail = '$payer_email'";
$result = mysqli_query($conDB, $sql) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conDB));    

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
  $sql = "UPDATE user_verified SET total_paid = total_paid + '$payment_amount' where user_mail = '$payer_email'";
}
else {
  $sql = "INSERT into user_verified (user_mail,total_paid) VALUES ('$payer_email', '$payment_amount')";
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_query($conDB, $sql) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conDB));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your user_mail is a UNIQUE KEY you would be able to use the option ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in the INSERT. You can do everything in just 1 query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_verified (user_mail,total_paid) VALUES ('$payer_email',$payment_amount) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total_paid = total_paid + $payment_amount";

mysqli_query($conDB, $sql);
```

Check this example of a table using UNIQUE KEY.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4919e2/1/0